# Como realizar a soma de valores que multipliquei?

Tags: sql

Realizei uma operação que multiplica a quantidade de valores pelo valor unitário de cada um, obtendo o valor total por produto. Como poderia somar os valores totais de todos os produtos? tentei com um Sum dentro de um Sum...

EDIT1: Tentei usar RollUp mas acabo estourando o limite de 100mb

Comment: Você poderia postar seu código SQL para melhor lhe indicarmos o uso do `sum`. Dependendo dos campos do `select`, pode exibir um `group by`. E você precisa especificar se é SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc.

Answer (score 0):

creio ser algo como :

```
select cod_produto , sum(valor_unitario * quantidade) valor_total
from   vendas
group by cod_produto
```